# Both SAM and cdk can make stack, SAM include cdk ? or cdk include SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I want to make two bucket(x,y) in `S3` and make a `lambda`.

My goal is uploading files to `S3(x)` and it triggers `lambda` then `lambda` create and put file in `S3(y)`

Currently, I am developing `lambda` function on `SAM`.

Deploying `lambda` function by `SAM`

And I made two S3 buckets by `cdk`.

Then manually adding `trigger` and `Iam policy` to `lambda` to access `S3`

However I want to do this all automatically.

So my idea is ,

1. `SAM` can make two `S3` bucket as stack and I don't need cdk anymore ?
2. `cdk` can include `SAM` development environment?
3. Any other way??

What is the best practice for this purpose??

Comment: Create everything in CDK and test your lambda with SAM: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/aws-serverless-application-model-sam-cli-aws-cloud-development-kit-cdk/

Comment: Thank you. I will try to install lambda project created by SAM  by CDK

Answer (score 0):

My `solution is

- Local development with SAM
- `AWS` deployment is carried out by `cdk` only, `SAM` doesn't work anything for deployment.

My folder structure is below

```
cdk / bin
      lib 
      cdk.json
      etc
      samproj/helloworld/app.py
             /samconfig.toml
             /template.yaml
             /etc
```

For local developing, in `samproj` directory, do something like this, [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html).

```
sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" -e events/event.json
```

And for `AWS` deployment by `cdk` project .

Just make `lambda` directly from `samproj/helloworld` directory in Stack.

```
export class CdkVrBaseStack extends Stack {
    const lambda_ = new lambda.Function(this, 'TestLambda', {
      functionName: 'testLambda',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('samproj/helloworld'),
      handler: 'index.handler',
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
```